# Setup the maximum value, and the width of a pie chart using charts

Tags: ios, swift, graph, charts

Hi there I'm working with Charts library and I've build some graphs, but I want to do something special with a PieChart and I can't do it yet I don't know which could be the properties to setup my pie graph like y want. Ok then I want to setup a maximum value to 100  for the graph, by setting up this, I guess that my graph will show just the number that I'm trying to show in this case es 50 and the other part of the graph should look empty. I hope yo can help me.

[This is what I have now the graph has just one Double value that value is 50](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmUx8.jpg)

[This is the way that the graph should look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Zx7Hw.jpg)

Comment: show your code.

Comment: Ok I'll let my code as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
 func createPieGraphRedemptions() {
        var chart = PieChartView()
        chart = PieChartView(frame: CGRect(x: 229, y: 40, width: 165, height: 165))
        let yVals: [Double] = [50]
        var entries = [ ChartDataEntry]()
        for (i, v) in yVals.enumerated() {
            let entry = ChartDataEntry()
            entry.x = Double( i)
            entry.y = v

            entries.append( entry)
        }
        let set = PieChartDataSet( values: entries, label: "Pie Chart")

        set.colors = [UIColor.red]

        let data = PieChartData( dataSet: set)
        //data.setDrawValues(false)
        chart.data = data
        chart.noDataText = "No hay datos disponibles"
        chart.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
        chart.legend.enabled = false
        chart.chartDescription?.text = ""
        chart.highlighter = nil



        self.view.addSubview(chart)
    }
```